# Canvas performance in Dart

Tags: html, performance, canvas, dart

This problem is related to my framework VilTAGE (https://github.com/ViliX64/VilTAGE). It's an ASCII web game framework, that renders to Canvas. The problem is, that the drawing time is twice as long as the computation time.

The way the rendering works now is that there is a HashMap of each CharNode (an object, with a text character, color, etc..) and CanvasElement, that has the text drawn onto it. When the loop wants to draw a CharNode (15-30x a second), it goes through the HashMap, find required CanvasElement and renders it to the main CanvasElement. (See https://github.com/ViliX64/VilTAGE/blob/master/lib/etc/utility.dart).

The individual CanvasElement snaps are small (usually about 10x10). They are drawn using drawImage(..);

The problem is, that in a game with 70x40 CharNodes, the game runs (unsuprisingly) very slow and even more, when compiled to JavaScript.

Is there any obvious mistake I am making or could you please give me any tips of improving the performance?

EDIT 1: It runs the slowest on Firefox and IE. Performance on Google Chrome is better.

Comment: You are looping through the hashmap instead of fetching directly by key as it is supposed to be used. Changing this should give you a small speedup.

Comment: I know that, but I need the values to be the same. Even when I overriden the == operator, it didn't return the required CharNode. Thanks for the tip, though.

Comment: I have updated the code, so it won't iterate through the hashmap anymore. It did improved a performance mostly on Firefox and IE :)

Comment: Most likely you forgot to override [hashCode](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:core.Object#id_hashCode) when overriding ==.

Comment: I've solved it in a different way. Now it's creating a String, that contains those values (not in readable format, but it's comparable). The HashMap is now <String, CanvasElement> and I don't have to iterate through the whole HashMap now :)

Comment: Have you tried to use the analyer of chrome or IE to see what functions use most of CPU time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If** it works like it does in javascript, your issue is probably with the fact that you're cacheing a CanvasElement and that the drawImage have to retrieve the bitmapData from it each time it is called. This is a really expensive operation.

You could try to cache the imageData with getImageData and draw it with putImageData (both are CanvasRenderingContext2D methods)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll give you back results in under 10 minutes.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the code and now I am caching only the ImageData. It did improved the performance, but only a little (by avg. 2 FPS).
The edited code can be found here: https://github.com/ViliX64/VilTAGE/blob/master/lib/etc/utility.dart

Comment: Well, it seems I was wrong, sorry for the confusion : http://jsperf.com/canvas-drawimage-vs-putimagedata/3

Comment: I think it actually did had a little impact on the speed. The test can't be compared to this case, since VilTAGE is drawing lots of tiny images.